# Java conditional checks and assignment

Tags: java, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

I am looking for a more efficient way to perform the following action, where I am appending the return value of a method to an array. However if the return is null i want to perform another action and not change the array.

```
Object[] myVal = new Object[10];
Object temp;
temp = myFunction();
if(temp != null) {
    myVal[count++] = temp;
} else {
    System.Exit();
}
```

Where I want to assign a variable to the return of a method, but provide an 'inline' check to carry out another action if the value returned is null.

Something like:

```
myVal = (myFunction() != null) ? [output of expression]: System.Exit();
```

Is there any method like this?

Comment: What's inefficient about your current code?

Comment: At least the `new Object` part.

Comment: I'm looking to try an avoid creating an instance of the temp Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ((myVal = myFunction()) == null) System.exit(0);
else // do your work
```

**Note:** Usage of ternary operators is not recommended because code becomes hard to read.

Comment: if myVal was an array that i am adding the return value onto the end of, would this add the null value? i ideally want to check for the value before i would add it onto the end of the array.

Comment: Normally use temp instead of myVal...if ((temp = myFunction()) != null) myVal[index] = temp;

Answer (score 6):

```
myVal = myFunction();
if (myVal == null) System.exit(0);
```

No need for a temp variable.

Comment: I think the OP wants to avoid the variable assignment when the method returns `null`. Of course, if he's actually doing `System.exit(0)` it won't matter.

Comment: @GriffeyDog "Avoid the assignment?" Doesn't that mean to keep it assigned to null, which he is trying to avoid anyway?